# Can a transcendental number be an infimum of a set of rationals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say I have a set of rational numbers $S \in \mathbb{Q}$. I know that $S$ can have an irrational infimum, for example the set $\{s \in S \:|\: s^3 > 2\}$ has irrational infimum $2^{1/3}$.

However, what about a number that isn't a solution of any polynomial, e.g. transcendental numbers? I have a feeling that a number such as $\pi$ can't be the infimum to any set of rationals, since there will always be a lower bound greater than $\pi$. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: No, if you had more examples under your belt, you would have a different feeling. How about the set of rationals between $1$ and $2$ for which the cosine is negative?

Comment: If you take the set of *all* rationals greater than $\pi$, the infimum will be $\pi$ itself....

Answer (score 4):

Take the partial sums of $\sum_k 1/k^2 = \pi^2/6$ as a counterexample.

**Edit** To fit your case exactly, consider taking the infimum of the set of partial sums of $-\sum_k 1/k^2$, which is $-\pi^2/6$, clearly a transcendental number

Comment: @Lubin see the edit, you just need to negate it.

Comment: Hmm, surely $\frac{1}{k^2}$?

Comment: @MPW thank you, dumb typo, sorry

Comment: Why is $\pi^2$ is clearly transcendental? (assuming $\pi$ is)

Comment: @user2345215 i thought it is generally known that any non constant algebraic functions of 1 variable, applied to a transcendetal number, yield transcendental output.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the set

$$S = \{q: q \in \mathbb{Q} \mbox{ and } q > \pi\}$$

What is its infimum?

Answer (score 2):

What about the successive decimal approximations 3, 3.1, 3.141, 3.1415, etc which increase to $\pi$? If you must have $\inf$ instead of $\sup$, use 1-3, 1-3.1, 1-3.14, 1-3.141, 1-3.1415, etc which decrease to $1-\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

While transcendental numbers can be complex numbers too, let me assume that you implicitly mean real numbers here.

**Every** real number is an infimum of a set of rationals. Simply because the rational numbers are dense in $\Bbb R$, so given $x$, we immediatly have that $\{q\in\Bbb Q\mid x<q\}$ is a set of rational numbers whose infimum is $x$ itself.

Whether or not we can **express** in a [non trivial] formula in the language of mathematics (standard field operations, sigma notation, the "usual" functions that we accept to exist, etc.) what this set of rationals is a different question.

Some transcendental numbers will have to be referred by themselves, as the set above is defined in terms of $x$. It's not an issue, we already know that $x$ exists, so we don't need to define it from this set, rather we have all the real numbers, now given a real number $x$ we define a set of rational numbers that $x$ is its infimum. There's no circularity here.

Others we can express in other terms, e.g. $\pi$ can be approximated with certain sums and roots, and so we can easily define a set of rational numbers whose infimum is $\pi$. Essentially any number that you can constructively show to exist has a reasonable definition that allows us to write a [possibly very complicated] set of rational numbers that it is its infimum.